# Why my answer is getting accepted with set but not with vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, set

Question is We have to find if there is any sub array whose sum is zero.Return true if possible and false if not.
Time contraint:3 seconds

This is the code using unordered set getting accepted .

```
bool subArrayExists(int arr[], int n)
    {
        //Your code here
        int sum=0;
        unordered_set<int>s;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            sum=sum+arr[i];
            if(sum==0||s.find(sum)!=s.end()){
               return true;
            }
            s.insert(sum);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This is the vector solution which is giving tle.

```
bool subArrayExists(int arr[], int n)
    {
        //Your code here
        int sum=0;
        vector<int>v;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            sum=sum+arr[i];
            if(sum==0||find(v.begin(),v.end(),sum)!=v.end()){
                return true;
            }
            v.push_back(sum);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: what are the time constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
if(sum==0||s.find(sum)!=s.end()){
```

is very different from this line

```
if(sum==0||find(v.begin(),v.end(),sum)!=v.end()){
```

First, a `unordered_set` does not store the same element twice. In general this would make a difference, though as you stop when you encounter the first duplicate, the number of elements in the vector and in the set are the same here.

Next, [`std::unordered_set::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) has average constant complexity while `std::find` is linear. `std::unordered_set::find` can make use of the internal structure of the set, thats why it exists in the first place. You don't want to use `std::find` with a unordered set, because that would be less performant. With the unordered set your algorithm is `O(N)` with the vector it is `O(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N)` which is `O(N^2)`.

Note that the version with the unodered set could be made even faster. Currently you are searching the element twice. Once here `s.find(sum)` and another time when inserting it. You could do it both at once when you use the return value from `unodered_set::insert`. It returns a pair of an iterator (pointing to the element) and a `bool` that indicates whether the element was inserted. When that `bool` is `false`, the element was already present before:

```
        sum=sum+arr[i];
        auto ret = s.insert(sum);
        if(sum==0 || ret.second == false){
           return true;
        }
```

Comment: "You don't want to use std::find with a set, because that would be less performant".. Don't you mean `vector` ?

Comment: @Tootsie no, I mean set. `unodered_set::find` is average constant but `std::find` with a set is only linear, and on top of that incrementing set iterators as done by `std::find` is costly

Comment: Thanks, I misread.. Btw, isn't `find` with a set O(log(n)) ?  Should be a tree structure

Comment: @Tootsie sorry I was mixing up `std::set` and `std::unordered` set. For the first it is logarithmic